# not able to read contents in other user home

Tags: linux, permissions

i have two users of same group, have given the read permission on the home folder of "ctbadm" for the group, but "oracle" user not able to read the contents of ctbadm user, Please help

[image]

Comment: You always need the execute bit to browse directories.

Comment: yeah added it, thank you all, it worked after adding x bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add execution permission to the directory.

For a directory, the execute (x) permission means you can open the directory, cd to it, access it's sons... etc.
Reading permission (r) only allows to list the sons.

So, do a `chmod g+x ctbadm` as root or user ctbadm and it should work.